# Fail to build vlc

Tags: linux, centos, vlc

I want to start developing for vlc, but i have a little problem building it, when i ./configure i get the following error:

```
configure: error: Could not find libmad on your system: you may get it from
http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/. 
Alternatively you can use --disable-mad to disable   the mad plugin.
```

I am using centos OS (CentOS release 6.5 (Final))

I tried to follow some tutorials on the web, but it didnt seem to help, and it seems pretty basic.

How can i install those dependencies easily ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install it manually via your package management system. So in this case:

```
yum install libmad-devel
```

Alternatively, you can compile without libmad using the command line options they told you.

Comment: You need to install the `-devel` package, not just the runtime package.

Comment: Oops, I left that out. Good call.

Comment: that fixed the problem, but now i get: 
No package 'libavcodec' found

Comment: Well you're installing VLC from source, so all the dependencies aren't being resolved. You could use "yum install vlc" which will pull in all the dependencies for you.

Comment: Installing vlc will only bring in runtime deps, not build-time deps. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should install the `libmad-devel` package. In general, for a library named `foo`, you should install the `libfoo-devel` package.